# Neomodel: specify neo4j database name in connection string

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

In the neomodel documentation it's possible to specify the neo4j connection string using the following statement:

```py
from neomodel import config
config.DATABASE_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7687'
```

On neo4j 4.1, I am using multiple databases under the same server. I would like to specify the database I am using either in the connection string or somewhere else.

In py2neo I can do something like this:

```py
graph = Graph(host='localhost', port=7687, auth=('neo4j','pwd'), name='dbname')
```

Is there any way to do this in neomodel?

Comment: neomodel is not updated for a long time, you need to use a different library/driver

Comment: I need the object graph mapper and meta classes functionality in order to integrate this with django. Unfortunately, py2neo doesn't provide the same functionality. I don't know any other library I can use.

Comment: For anyone coming to this check the NeoModel issue tracker - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/issues/541 where the op asked the same questions. This will allow for an easy reference for when this is supported outside of issuing a USE query to swap databases

Answer (score 0):

from the docs ([link](https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20database%20name)):

> Setting the database name, if different from the default one:

```
# Using the URL only
config.DATABASE_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7687/mydb'

# Using config option
config.DATABASE_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7687'
config.DATABASE_NAME = 'mydb'
```